# linq to sql - sort by attribute in XML field

Tags: .net, linq

I've got a SQL table that contains an XML field in it.

What I want to do is get all the data from the SQL table sorted by an attribute of the root element in each of the XML field's data..

So I have a table of items with a "userid" (guid),a "description" (xml) and a "type" (int).

A single record looks like this:

```
1205159E-B4F9-41A9-955E-A3554AF1F21A
1
<book displayText="new book">
    <txtTitle>new book</txtTitle>
    <txtSubTitle>book 1</txtSubTitle>
    <txtAuthor>book 1 author</txtAuthor>
</book>
```

I'm trying to return a sorted list by "displayText".. simple text based sort..

I've tried this

```
return (from i in mContext.Items
        where i.Type == Type
          &&  i.UserID == UserID
        orderby (string)i.Description.Attribute("displayName")
        select i).ToList();
```

but I keep getting:
Method 'System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute Attribute(System.Xml.Linq.XName)' has no supported translation to SQL

Am I asking to much from linq..???  surely not..  or should I just bite the bullet and create a sql sproc and do it in the database..???

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq-to-Sql cannot interpret the attribute - it has no parallel in the translation to Sql Server, and thus when it is submitted it returns that error that you received.

You can still perform Linq-related actions using things like Attributes that are only accessible on the client side. In order to do this, you first need to bring the data down to the client side (using a `ToList()` command on a Linq-to-Sql query), and then sorting it locally. For example:

```
var query = mContext.Items.Where(i => i.Type == Type && i.UserID == UserID).ToList();
return query.OrderBy(i => i.Description.Attribute("displayName")).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Yaakov.. this worked with a slight mod... I ended up using OrderBy(i => i.Description.FirstAttribute.Value)...
But you certainly had me heading in the right direction..  Thanks very much...

Answer (score 1):

You cant do this by linq2sql !!! 
The result of the linq is a SQL query, thw function you use in the linq2sql is .net function that dont have any implement function in SQL.
You can get all the data to List and by code to sort that(more time!!!)

During that conversion, it is just a method call, nothing more. Linq to Sql understands certain method calls, and yours is not one of them. Hence the error.

On the surface, this seems like it should work. You write reusable queries and compose them from other queries. However, what you are actually saying is: "during the processing of each row on the database server, call this method", which it obviously can't do. The fact that it takes an `IQueryable<T>` and returns an `IQueryable<T>` does not make it special.

Comment: by mistake i not enter the all answer,sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are asking too match from Linq to SQL.

What you need is retrieving Xml from database via Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities, and then use Linq to Xml to process data in memory.

```
return  mContext.Items.Where(i => i.Type == Type && i.UserID == UserID)
                .ToList()
                .OrderBy(i => (string)XElement.Parse(i.Description)
                                              .Attribute("displayName"));
```